# WPF MVVM code for button binding with a parameter

Tags: c#, button, mvvm, combobox, binding

I have a WPF application that has multiple comboboxes and buttons.  I am learning the MVVM model with this application.  The first combobox will display a list of database instances.  This is done at the start of the application.  This works fine.

There is a button object next to the database instances combobox.  When the user clicks this button I need to get the contents of the database instance combobox and use it in a call to get all the databases in that instance.  I am using a RelayCommand (ICommand) for the actions.  The action for the button is getting setup correctly.  I have a method SelectedDatabase in the DBInstance class but it is null when I click the button.

In the LoadDBInfo method below the selectedItem parameter is null.

Here is my XAML:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbxRLFDBInstances" ItemsSource="{Binding DBInstances}" 
                  SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedDBInstance}" SelectedValuePath="value" 
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="28" Margin="189,87,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                  Width="250" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="14.667" 
                  IsEditable="True"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnRLFDBLoadDBInfo" Content="Load DB Info" Command="{Binding LoadDBInfoCommand}" 
                CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedDBInstance}"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="475,89,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                Width="101" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="14.667" Background="#FFE8F9FF" 
                ToolTip="Click here after choosing or typing in the datbase instance.  This will populate the database list."/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="cbxRLFDBName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="28" Margin="189,132,0,0" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding DBDatabases}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedDBDatabase}" 
                  SelectedValuePath="value" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="250" FontFamily="Arial" 
                  FontSize="14.667" IsEditable="True" IsReadOnly="True"
                  ToolTip="Once a database is choosen the table list will automatically be populated."/>
```

Here is my ViewModel:

```
namespace DatabaseTest.ViewModel
{

    class RLFDatabaseTableViewModel
    {

    Utilities dbtUtilities = new Utilities();


    public RelayCommand LoadDBInfoCommand
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public RLFDatabaseTableViewModel()
    {
        LoadDBInstances();

        LoadDBInfoCommand = new RelayCommand(LoadDBInfo);
    }


    #region Database Instance

    public IList<DBInstance> DBInstances
    {
        get;
        set;
    }


    public void LoadDBInstances()
    {
        IList<DBInstance> dbInstances = nList<DBInstance>();
        DataTable dt = SmoApplication.EnumAvailableSqlServers(false);

        dbInstances.Add(new DBInstance { DBInstanceName = "fal-conversion\\mun2012ci" });
        dbInstances.Add(new DBInstance { DBInstanceName = "fal-conversion\\mun2014ci" });

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                dbInstances.Add(new DBInstance { DBInstanceName = dr["Name"].ToString() });
            }
        }

        DBInstances = dbInstances;
    }


    #endregion Database Instance


    #region Database Names

    public IList<DBDatabase> DBDatabases
    {
        get;
        set;
    }


    public void LoadDBDatabases()
    {
        IList<DBDatabase> dbDatabases = new List<DBDatabase>();

        dbDatabases.Add(new DBDatabase { DBDatabaseName = "DB - A" });
        dbDatabases.Add(new DBDatabase { DBDatabaseName = "DB - B" });



        DBDatabases = dbDatabases;
    }

    #endregion Database Names


    #region Button Cammands

    void LoadDBInfo(object selectedItem)
    {
        SqlConnection sqlConn = null;
        IList<DBDatabase> dbDatabaseNames = new List<DBDatabase>();


       // string selectedItem = dbInstances.
        //Setting the PUBLIC property 'TestText', so PropertyChanged event is fired 
        if (selectedItem == null)
            dbDatabaseNames = null;
        else
        {
            SelectedDBInstance = selectedItem as DBInstance;
            dbDatabaseNames = dbtUtilities.GetDBNames(sqlConn, _selectedDBInstance.ToString(),
                _selectedDBDatabase.ToString());
        }

        DBDatabases = dbDatabaseNames;
    }

    #endregion Button Commands
}
```

Here is my Model:

```
namespace DatabaseTest.Model
{
    public class RLFDatabaseTableModel { }


    public class DBInstance : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string strDBInstance;


        public override string ToString()
        {
            return strDBInstance;
        }


        public string DBInstanceName
        {
            get
            {
                return strDBInstance;
            }

            set
            {
                if (strDBInstance != value)
                {
                    strDBInstance = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("DBInstanceName");
                }
            }
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void RaisePropertyChanged(string property)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
            }
        }
    }

    public class DBDatabase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string strDBDatabase;


        public override string ToString()
        {
            return strDBDatabase;
        }


        public string DBDatabaseName
        {
            get
            {
                return strDBDatabase;
            }

            set
            {
                if (strDBDatabase != value)
                {
                    strDBDatabase = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("DBDatabaseName");
                }
            }
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void RaisePropertyChanged(string property)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:  This is my code to load the 2nd combobox, cbxRLFDBName,  The DBDatabase has the values but the combobox is not loaded.

```
public void LoadDatabases(string strDBInstanceName)
    {
        string strQuery;
        IList<DBDatabase> dbDatabases = new List<DBDatabase>();
        SqlConnection sqlUtilDBConn = null;


        try
        {
            if (sqlUtilDBConn != null)
            {
                sqlUtilDBConn.Close();
            }

            sqlUtilDBConn = dbtUtilities.LoginToDatabase(strDBInstanceName, "master");

            strQuery = "select name from sys.databases order by 1";

            using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery, sqlUtilDBConn))
            {
                SqlDataReader sqlDataRead = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (sqlDataRead.Read())
                {
                    string strDBNme = sqlDataRead.GetString(0);

                    dbDatabases.Add(new DBDatabase { DBDatabaseName = strDBNme });
                }

                sqlDataRead.Close();
                sqlCmd.Dispose();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exQuery)
        {
            string strMsg;


            strMsg = "GetNumRows: Error, '" + exQuery.Message + "', has occurred.";
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(strMsg);
        }

        DBDatabases = dbDatabases;
}
```

EDIT:  I have removed some of the code that is not needed in the hopes that this will be easier to read.  My issue is that combobox "cbxRLFDBInstances" with ItemsSource="{Binding DBInstances}" loads the combobox fine.  I also have another combobox, "cbxRLFDBName" with ItemsSource="{Binding DBDatabases}".  When I choose the appropriate database instance and click the Load DB Info button, LoadDatabases runs and I can see that DBDatabases has the information needed in it.  However the combobox is not loaded and I do not have a failure.  Why does one ItemsSource data binding work and the other does not?  I believe I am setting the class correctly but it seems lo=ike the binding is not happening?  What have I missed?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? This is huge to read and understand :D

Comment: When I get into the LoadDBInfo method, the passed selectedItem object is null. I need to get the contents of the databaseinstance combo boX.

Comment: is your Sql connection supposed to be null? `SqlConnection sqlConn = null;`

Comment: Yes the sql connection is null, I create that later. In my name for age button i have CommandPaeameter = "{Binding SelectedDBInstance"}, I expected thus to give me the contents of the Database Instsnce combo box as the selectedItem object to LoadDBInfo, however selectedItem is null and I need the instance name here. The sql connection cannot be created without that name.

Comment: in the else part of this if `if (selectedItem == null)`, is it supposed to be `dbDatabaseNames = dbtUtilities.GetDBNames(sqlConn, _selectedDBInstance.ToString(),
                _selectedDBDatabase.ToString());`? Because, here `(SelectedDBInstance = selectedItem as DBInstance;)` selected item is asigned to `SelectedDBInstance` and `_selectedDBInstance` is the string. I have no idea what you are upto. Still. :)

Comment: I can deal with the else code after I either get selectedItem set or get the contents of the Database Instance combobox.  Since selectedItem is null the code is moot.  I thought the CommandPaeameter = "{Binding SelectedDBInstance"} would trigger the SelectedDBInstance method and _selectedDBInstance would be populated.  I am very new to binding.  But what I really need help with is getting the value that is currently in the Database Instance combobox.  Once I have that, and hopefully a better understanding of binding, I can fix the code.

Comment: What I believe I need is a method to return the name in the database instance combobox.  Trying to figure this out now.  However I thought the SelectedDBInstance method would do this?  How does this method actually work?

Comment: I have an example [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/665546/Passing-Command-Parameter-for-Buttons-within-an) have a look! I am not much into Desktop apps. (Web here) :D

Comment: This gave me what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: @Prashanth Benny -- My second combobox is not being loaded, I added an EDIT above for the code that populates the DBDatabase class.  I have this in my xaml for the 2nd combobox, cmbxRLFDBName, ItemsSource="{Binding DBDatabases}".  Shouldn't the ItemsSource be loaded everytime the DBDabase class is loaded, or is it only at application load time?

Comment: Refer [this link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bethmassi/2007/09/19/binding-multiple-combo-boxes-to-the-same-data-source/). It might be of help to you.

Comment: @Prashanth Benny -- Thanks for the info. However I'm not trying to bind the same data source to two elements. The ItemsSource for these two comboboxes are different. Is you look at my xaml for the 2 comboxes their s setups are very similar. When DBInstances is set in code the combobox is loaded. When DBDatabases is set in code the combobox is not loaded. If the setup is the same and creation code is similar why isn't the second combobox being loaded? The difference is that the DBInstances is set at app startup, DBDatabases on button click.

Comment: I am still very confused on why the ItemsSource="{Binding DBInstances}" on cbxRLFDBInstances loads the combobox while ItemsSource="{Binding DBDatabases}" on cbxRLFDBName does not? Do I have to raise a change event or something?

Comment: Probably you have to edit the question with your current requirement and necessary code only. The code here is too huge! Very confusing! You would get better help if you do that. I have very less idea about MVVM and XAML. Somebody who knows the domain would be of more help. Alright? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code look fine to me, except for the `SelectedValuePath="value"` on the ComboBoxes. `SelectedValuePath` specifies a property on the selected item that is to be bound to the `SelectedValue`. `SelectedDBInstance` is of type `DBInstance` and `DBInstance` class does not define a `value` property, so I'd say you just have to remove `SelectedValuePath="value"` from the ComboBoxes.

**Edit:**
You need your ViewModel to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`:

```cs
class RLFDatabaseTableViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  private void RaisePropertyChanged(string property)
  {
    if (PropertyChanged != null) {
      PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }
  }

  // the rest of RLFDatabaseTableViewModel implementation ...
}
```

And then every time you change a property value inside ViewModel, you also need to call `RaisePropertyChanged` immediately after. For example:

```
DBDatabases = dbDatabaseNames;
RaisePropertyChanged("DBDatabases");
```

It is helpful to define your properties like so:

```
public string StringProperty
{
  get { return this.stringProperty; }
  set {
    this.stringProperty = value;
    this.RaisePropertyChanged("StringProperty");
  }
}
private string stringProperty;
```

Then you can just write

```
this.StringProperty = "new value";
```

and the new value will be set and a change notification sent.

You have to send the notifications because the View (XAML) and ViewModel are different classes and the View has no way of knowing that a property on the ViewModel has changed. If ViewModel implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, WPF will listen for property changes through the `PropertyChanged` event and update the View accordingly.

Comment: Hromadik-- It actually works. I was trying to figure it out but I don't know. But for the cbxRLFDBInstances combo box the selected name is in the value parameter

Comment: @Cass I just realised that you are using SelectedValue and SelectedValuePath, so that should work. I've always used SelectedItem instead of SelectedValue and SelectedValuePath. Check if SelectedDBInstance is being set, and if not, try using SelectedItem, that's always worked for me.

Comment: @Hromadik -- Can you take a look at my latest edit?  Any ideas on my issue?

Comment: @Cass I think the issue is that the last line `DBDatabases = dbDatabases;` sets the property, but the view (XAML) doesn't know that this happened. The view has to be notified that the value of a property has changed. You actually already do this in your models - by implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` and calling `RaisePropertyChanged(property)`. Just do the same thing in your view-model every time you change the value of a data-bound property. This notifies WPF engine that a property has changed and it will fetch its current value.

Comment: I am sorry, I'm a little confused.  I am not sure what I need to do in my viewmodel?  If I am already doing it in the Model why is that not notifying the UI?  In the ViewModel what needs to be an INotifyPropertyChanged class?

Comment: -- Why do I have to do this in the ViewModel if I have it in the Model code?  I have tried this and it still isn't working.  From what I ahve been researching it sounds like I need to raise a notify event on the combobox, but the combobox element isn't available in code.  How do I do this?

Comment: @Cass You have to do it in every class where you have data-bound properties whose value you want synchronised to the view. Whenever you use a binding, ie `ItemsSource="{Binding DBDatabases}"`, the control displays a copy of the property value (in this case a copy of the list in DBDatabases). When that value (the list itself or the values inside it) changes, you need to notify the control to fetch and display the new value - to do that you raise a `PropertyChanged` event with the specific property name (in this case DBDatabases) in the event args.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm just not getting it.  I have ItemsSource="{Binding DBDatabases}" DBDatabases is an ObservableCollection<DBDatabase>.  DBDatabases isn't a class is it, it's built on class DBDatabase.  I thought I had I needed except possibly the code to invoke a notify change property or something like that?  I have looked through a ton of examples and now I think I am over thinking this.  Do I need to setup and notify event handler for the DBDatabases?  Do you have an example of that?  I am feeling very stupid right now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to pass command parameter as selected izem from combobox, something like:

```
CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem,ElementName=yourComboBoxName}"
```

Comment: Just found this out

Comment: @iviica.moke -- Can you take a look at my latest edit?  Any ideas on my issue?

Comment: Im not sure, but maybe becouse you set your DBDatabase as list, and its initialize after button click, list populates but your UI wont be notified. Try to change that list to ObservableCollection becouse it allready implement collection changed and your UI will be notified on collection changed. When i bind to collection, i always use ObservableCollection. And your firs list is initialized in constructor, that why it shows items, but it wont show any changes on list becouse list dont implement INotifyCollectionChanged.

Comment: I cant write on hromadik, but use ObservableCollection property and your UI will be notified. Like this. ObservableCollection<DBDatabase> DBDatabases {get; set;}  and in constructor initialize that property like: DBDatabases = new ObservableCollection<DBDatabase>(); and it will work. I suggested to always use ObservableCollection when you want your UI to be notified.